# Getting 404 errors when trying to target local Micro Cloud Foundry

Tags: http-status-code-404, virtual-machine, cloud-foundry

I'm trying to install Micro Cloud Foundry on my machine using VirtualBox. My Micro Cloud Foundry is running, the network is up, services are running. But when I try to target my Micro Cloud Foundry (using vmc target <my domain>), I am getting the following error:

```
... FAILED
CFoundry::NotFound: 404: <html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>

For more information, see ~/.vmc/crash
```

The content of ~/.vmc/crash is:

```
cfoundry-0.5.3.rc7/lib/cfoundry/baseclient.rb:163:in `handle_error_response'
cfoundry-0.5.3.rc7/lib/cfoundry/baseclient.rb:137:in `handle_response'
cfoundry-0.5.3.rc7/lib/cfoundry/baseclient.rb:87:in `request'
cfoundry-0.5.3.rc7/lib/cfoundry/baseclient.rb:64:in `get'
cfoundry-0.5.3.rc7/lib/cfoundry/baseclient.rb:60:in `info'
cfoundry-0.5.3.rc7/lib/cfoundry/client.rb:40:in `new'
vmc-0.5.1.rc6/lib/vmc/cli/start/target.rb:26:in `block in target'
interact-0.5.2/lib/interact/progress.rb:98:in `with_progress'
vmc-0.5.1.rc6/lib/vmc/cli/start/target.rb:24:in `target'
mothership-0.5.1/lib/mothership/base.rb:66:in `run'
mothership-0.5.1/lib/mothership/command.rb:72:in `block in invoke'
mothership-0.5.1/lib/mothership/command.rb:86:in `instance_exec'
mothership-0.5.1/lib/mothership/command.rb:86:in `invoke'
mothership-0.5.1/lib/mothership/base.rb:55:in `execute'
vmc-0.5.1.rc6/lib/vmc/cli.rb:155:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
vmc-0.5.1.rc6/lib/vmc/cli.rb:166:in `save_token_if_it_changes'
vmc-0.5.1.rc6/lib/vmc/cli.rb:154:in `block in execute'
vmc-0.5.1.rc6/lib/vmc/cli.rb:103:in `wrap_errors'
vmc-0.5.1.rc6/lib/vmc/cli.rb:150:in `execute'
mothership-0.5.1/lib/mothership.rb:45:in `start'
vmc-0.5.1.rc6/bin/vmc:11:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/vmc:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/vmc:23:in `<main>'
```

The network of my virtual machine is set to "bridged adapter". Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the virtual machine menu and (a) restart the network, and if this does not work (b) relaunch the DNS and then restart the network (I don't have my VM in front of me right now, but there are two different menu items for DNS and network).

Comment: hi, i've restarted, reconfigured everything a several times, but still  the same result. i am getting a 404 error after the command vmc target <domain>. Are you using the vmc client or cf?

Comment: I am using vmc on a Mac (cf does not work for me). I usually refresh DNS (option 2 in the VM) and then restart network (option 9). It worked every time so far for me.

Comment: cf is for v2, and MCF is currently at v1, so you should stick with vmc for now.